# href and tr click avoid overlap

Tags: javascript, onclick, row, href

I have a table rows which uses javascript to open certain menus when clicked based on selected row. I also have an `<a href>` tag used to open the link or redirect somewhere else.

The problem is, when I clicked the `<a href>` link, the table row is also executed which opens the menus.

its PHP/Javascript language.

This is the script for table tr:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"enableDialogs(1)\";>";
```

For the `<a>` link in the same row:

```
echo "<td><a href='?folder={$filedir}'>{$list}</a></td>";
```

Question is, how do i avoid overlap of both on click function?

Comment: Hmm. Well, the problem is that the `tr` click handler is executing even if the `a` click handler is also executing. The answer seems to be detecting which element is currently being executed to determine if the `tr` handler should be "handled".

Comment: with jQuery it would be a simple case of adding `event.stopPropogation()` to the anchor click handler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic case of event bubbling. As some of the comments suggest take advantage of the callback from the subscribed element, reference the first argument, and stop the bubbling from the  tag. Assume `myElement` is 1 DOM node of your `<a>`.

```
myElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

Of course the jQuery callback works the same

```
$(myElement).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a single function that will check if the menu is open already.

If it is open it will continue to redirect or do whatever your code does at the moment. If it isn't, it simply opens it.

Basically, let the function take care of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the event propagation.

***[See the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GzvSj/2/)***.

*The javascript code:*

```
function stopPropagation(e) {
    if(!e) var e = window.event;

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
       e.cancelBubble = true;
       e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

*The php code:*

```
echo "<td><a href='?folder={$filedir}' onclick=\"stopPropagation(event)\">{$list}</a></td>";
```

​